# ValueError: invalid literal for int()

Tags: python, int

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "school.py", line 86, in ?
    numthreads = int(sys.argv[1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int()
```

Line 86:  `numthreads = int(sys.argv[1])`

Any answers? I am a really newbie in using python so I will really appreciate some help.

Comment: `sys.argv[1]` is not what is expected (and the error says why that is wrong); what *is* the actual value?

Answer (score 1):

The value coming from `sys.argv[1]` must be able to be converted to an `int`

```
>>> int(5)     # Okay! Converting int to int (no-op)
5

>>> int(5.1)   # Okay! Converting float to int
5

>>> int('c')   # Nope! Cannot convert char to int

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    int('c')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'c'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible that `sys.argv[1]` is an empty string in your case. Make sure that the item you're trying to convert is also an `integer`, and not a string with letters / symbols in it.

Also note that `sys.argv` is a list of arguments where the `0` indexed string is the script name itself, so for the command `file.py -arg1 -arg2`, the array would be `['file.py','-arg1','-arg2']`